# i would like to change uploaded images with php

Tags: php, html

php block

```
    if ($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'] != "") {
        $newname = "image01.jpg";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "_include/img/slider-images/$newname");
    }
    header("location: manage.php"); 
    exit();

}
```

html block

```
            <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
```

this code doesn΄t work. i checked permissions and everything seems fine.
any ideas?

Comment: What are you **changing** ?

Comment: Please show us your **full** and **real** code! (including your entire html form)

Comment: If you want to upload sepecific file there is no need to have file input in your form.What you expecting?

Comment: Your braces aren't matched, you have an extra `}` at the end with no matching `{`

Comment: So you want to change name of the uploaded file?..don't you?

Comment: i have a slider and i want to create through php a dynamic way to change the images of the slider

Comment: i created a form    <form action="manage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  with 4 inputs like the code i posted

Comment: and inside php i used the php code that i posted